# C++ Loop while not equal to either two values

Tags: c++, character, do-while

What am I doing wrong? I have a menu and can loop while cLetter not equal to 'Q'.

I want to be able to enter 'Q' or 'q' and quit the loop. Can't seem to get the syntax correct.

**EDIT** I was requested by the moderator to improve the question. Not sure what more there is to add. For the do-while loop I want it to continue to loop until EITHER "Q" or "q" is entered. When either "Q" or "q" is entered, the program should quit the loop.

// Begin Program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double Num1;
    double Num2;
    double sum;
    double difference;
    double product;
    double quotient;

    char cLetter; // Selecting Integers
    cout << "Please enter an integer: ";
    cin >> Num1;
    cout << "Please enter another integer: ";
    cin >> Num2;

    do {

        cout << "Select a letter to perform a calculation:" << endl; // Main Menu
        cout << "A for Addition" << endl;
        cout << "S for Subtraction" << endl;
        cout << "M for Multiplication" << endl;
        cout << "D for Division (BUT NOT BY ZERO)" << endl;
        cout << "N to enter 2 new numbers" << endl;
        cout << "Q to Quit" << endl;
        cin >> cLetter;

        //Perform Calculations

        sum = Num1 + Num2;
        difference = Num1 - Num2;
        product = Num1 * Num2;
        quotient = Num1 / Num2;

        //Choices Made
        if ((cLetter == 'A') || (cLetter == 'a')) //Addition
        {
            cout << "Addition" << endl;
            cout << "Sum = " << sum << endl;
        }
        else if ((cLetter == 'S') || (cLetter == 's')) //Subtraction
        {
            cout << "Subtraction" << endl;
            cout << "Difference = " << difference << endl;
        }
        else if ((cLetter == 'M') || (cLetter == 'm')) //Multiplication
        {
            cout << "Multiplication" << endl;
            cout << "Product = " << product << endl;
        }
        else if (((cLetter == 'D') && (Num2 == '0')) ||
                 ((cLetter == 'd') && (Num2 == '0'))) // Cannot be divided by zero
        {
            cout << "Cannot Divide by Zero!" << endl;

        }
        else if ((cLetter == 'D') || (cLetter == 'd')) //Division
        {
            cout << "Division" << endl;
            cout << "Quotient = " << quotient << endl;
        }
        else if ((cLetter == 'N') || (cLetter == 'n')) // New Integers
        {
            cout << "Please enter an integer: ";
            cin >> Num1;
            cout << "Please enter another integer: ";
            cin >> Num2;
        }

        else if ((cLetter == 'Q') || (cLetter == 'q')) // Quitting
        {
            cout << "Quitting" << endl; // Invalid Statement
        }
        else  // invalid letter
        {
            cout << "Invalid letter, enter letter from list" << endl; // Invalid Statement
        }

    }
//    while ((cLetter != 'Q') || (cLetter != 'q'));  //can't seem to get this to work. Next line does.
    while (cLetter != 'Q');
    cout << "Goodbye!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

// End Program

Comment: You want to 'and' those conditions using &&.

Comment: If the letter is `'Q'` (`cLetter != 'Q'` is false), is `cLetter != 'q'` true or false?

Comment: Your problem is not syntax. Your problem is logic. Your loop termination condition is "not ( (letter is not 'Q') or (letter is not 'q')". If you paid attention in class when boolean algebra was taught, you would've learned that "not (A or B)" is equivalent to "(not A) and (not B)". As such, your expression is logically equivalent to "(not (letter is not 'Q')) amd (not (letter is not 'q'))", or "(letter is 'Q') and (letter is 'q')". Since a single letter cannot be both 'Q' and 'q', the loop condition will never be met. Q.E.D.

Comment: Another thing: you only accept the input of the 2 numbers before the do-while loop is entered.

Answer (score 2):

A letter can't be both `q` and `Q`. Therefore, **every** letter is either not equal to `q` or not equal to `Q`. You need to use the logical **and** operator (`&&`), not the logical **or** (`||`) operator:

```
do {
    // code
} while (cLetter != 'q' && cLetter != 'Q');
// Here ----------------^
```

Comment: Thanks!!! I knew it was something simple that I was missing. Now it works correctly.